# Knex does not end connection Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I am testing knex.js behavior with Postgres database.

#### Files

database-configuration.json

```
{
  "client": "pg",
  "connection": {
    "host" : "localhost",
    "port" : "5432",
    "user" : "postgres",
    "password" : "",
    "database" : "test-database",
    "charset" : "utf8"
  },
  "pool": {
    "min" : 0,
    "max": 7
  }
}
```

database.connector.js

```
module.exports = require('knex')(require('../configuration/database-configuration.json'));
```

So when I want to test connection:

```
database = require('../database.connector')
database.raw('SELECT 1;').then(function (data) {
    logger.info(data);
  }).catch(function (error) {
    logger.error(error);
  });
logger.info('finished');
```

Connection is established and query is done. However the process (node process) does not end - it hangs for some reason. It actually looks like the query is not yet done - `logger.info('finished');` is never called.

Where is my mistake?

#### Edit

the result I get is

```
{

    "command":"SELECT",
    "rowCount":1,
    "oid":null,
    "rows":[
        {
            "?column?":1
        }
    ],
    "fields":[
        {
            "name":"?column?",
            "tableID":0,
            "columnID":0,
            "dataTypeID":23,
            "dataTypeSize":4,
            "dataTypeModifier":-1,
            "format":"text"
        }
    ],
    "_parsers":[
        null
    ],
    "rowAsArray":false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, right so I totally forgot that knex created connection pool that prevented process from stopping. Program worked as it supposed to work, and I failed to see everything.

I will not delete this as it might help somebody

Comment: Hi! what's the solution for this? How did you close the connection pool?

Comment: Holy cow I have no idea what the actual f*** was this. I will just investigate and see how and what was i thinking back then.. I will post back. Looks like the issue was that min value in pool was 0 and not 1. In addition to that, I found out that if you are using in-memory sqlite database ("connection": ":memory:")  connection pool should have both min and max values set to 1....

Comment: @Reiion yep there are no problems when min = 1